# Powershell - Get-QADUser - Excluding

Tags: powershell, filter

I tend to get e-mails often on the weekend saying "i think my password expired - can you check for me?".  So i created a simple script to check it on Friday and E-Mail it to me so i can reference it on the weekend.  We have a bunch of shared mailboxes and I'm trying to exclude them but its been a while and I feel like i'm forgetting something.

```
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot $root | Select Name,PasswordStatus| Where-Object FirstName -notlike "Shared" | Sort Name,PasswordStatus | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header
```

I've tried a ton of different ways to exclude the name 'Shared' but it still comes up when i output it into e-mail.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for using the -Like filter would be:

```
 Where-Object { $_.FirstName -notlike '*Shared*' }
```

The -Like operator does a wildcard match.  If you don't include any wildcard characters, you're essentially requiring an exact match (equivalent to $_.FirstName -neq 'Shared')

Comment: Where-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command 
again. - I get this error

Comment: Are you sure the property name is "FirstName" and not "GivenName"?  Not running the Quest cmdlets, so I can't test that.

Comment: both GivenName and Firstname exist - I did a test in 1 line of code and i can return the value successfully but when I attempt to filter like you stated it doesnt work.

Comment: Take a look at that Select - you're not passing the FirstName property, just Name and PassWordStatus

Comment: Good catch but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I can't explain that.